# Jest --findRelatedTests not finding related test

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs

When I run the command `jest --bail --findRelatedTests src/components/BannerSet/BannerSet.tsx`
 I get the following message:

```
No tests found, exiting with code 1
Run with `--passWithNoTests` to exit with code 0
No files found in C:\Users\user\code\repo.
Make sure Jest's configuration does not exclude this directory.
To set up Jest, make sure a package.json file exists.
Jest Documentation: facebook.github.io/jest/docs/configuration.html
Pattern: .\\src\\components\\BannerSet\\BannerSet.tsx - 0 matches
```

However I do have the files ready:

```
src/components/BannerSet/BannerSet.test.tsx
src/components/BannerSet/BannerSet.tsx
```

Why cant Jest find the related tests? Running just `jest` works perfectly fine.

Comment: Did you try this? `jest pathoffile`

Comment: That works if I give the test file, but that's not what I want. Because I want Jest to find the related test to the given component

Comment: Then you can put all the test files in `__tests__` folder to auto pickup.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the `roots` configuration ensure you include your source directory in the list of folders.

I ran into this issue and found it was because I was using the `roots` option in my jest configuration and was only referencing the `test` folder.  The below issue and roots documentation point out:

> **roots** is used by the internals of Jest to locate test files *and* **source files**

Related information:

- Docs: https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#roots-arraystring
- Issue: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/11527